# "Files" favorite disappeared in Gnome Shell, how to bring it back?

Tags: gnome

I have installed gnome shell with Ubuntu, and it works pretty well. I may have removed accidently the "Files" favorite in the Activity menu but it is impossible to put it back on the favorites dock. If I open a folder and right click on the icon of the folder that appear un the favorites dock there is no option "Add to favorites", so no possibility to bring "Files" favorite back in the dock.
Any idea?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I don't really understand. Open the App overview, right click on Files and then Add to favorites. Doesn't it work?

Comment: No it doesn't work, here is the problem! Anyway, I had to reinstall the system so the problem is gone...